# Roxyfileman Publishing Error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am building a CMS in Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition in ASP.Net MVC 5, Today I have finished my project, I used **roxyfileman** File Manager in my project to let users download and upload images and pdf media and I am very glad to say that this a great tool and works well on my development machine.

Now I want to deploy my project, so I am using Visual Studio's publish option to publish this project.

But I am getting this error while publishing.

```
Error: Copying file UserUploads\myfiles\Uploads\Images\DSC_2987.jpg to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\UserUploads\myfiles\Uploads\Images\DSC_2987.jpg failed. Could not find file 'UserUploads\myfiles\Uploads\Images\DSC_2987.jpg'.    CivilContractorMVCApp       0   0       IntelliSense    1
```

Note: I manually pasted **DSC_2987.jpg** file in **UserUploads\myfiles\Uploads\Images** folder but still getting above error.

Need your help.